# Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function error in AngularJS web page

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie on AngularJS. I have the following angularJS code

```
(function () {
    getDataFactory = function ()
    {
        return {
            callWebApi: function (reqData)
            {
                alert(reqData);
            }
        }
    }
    patientCategoryController = function ($http, $scope, getDataFactory) {
        // The following line is the culprit. If this is commented, I dont get the error. 
        // But it works, ie. when UNcommented, I get the messagebox showing     
        // "someDataToPass"!! So whats wrong???
        angular.element(document).ready(getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass'));
    }
    patientCategoryController.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', 'getDataFactory'];
    angular.module('demoApp', []);
    angular.module('demoApp').controller('patientCategoryController', patientCategoryController);
    angular.module('demoApp').factory('getDataFactory', getDataFactory);    
}());
```

I found the method call

```
angular.element(document).ready(getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass'));
```

is the problem.
So I am missing some thing very basic. Can someone please guide me on this. The HTML is absolute basic skeleton. I get this error in Chrome browser, right click and then select inspect page element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to pass the function body as a `ready` parameter, not the function return value, so this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass'));
```

should become:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
   getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass');
})
```

---

See it here: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a void function result do the document.ready method.
Here're two possible fixes:

1. Using document.ready

```html
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
  getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass'));
});
```

2. Not using document.ready

   `getDataFactory.callWebApi('someDataToPass'));`

Comment: Thank You, your first suggestion as well as the second one also worked.

Comment: I believe your controller will be called when the DOM structure is initialized, so you don't really need to handle document.ready event.

Comment: Yes, now I understand. Deeply appreciate your effort. Thanks. It was helpful.